# is sql faster than plsql in oracle

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, bulkinsert, query-performance

update using bulk collect or normal merge ?

I am trying to check the performance of update by using bulk collect and normal merge. 
I see that the performance is better when we use simple merge in a anonymous block. 
When I use bulk collect, it takes more time.

If normal update (merge) is faster than bulk collect, then why oracle has introduced it? Where do we actually see the benefit of bulk collect?

```
declare 
l_start integer;
l_end integer;
begin
l_start := dbms_utility.get_time;
merge into test111 t1
using test112 t2
on (t1.col1 = t2.col3)
when matched then update 
set t1.col2 = t1.col2*5;
l_end := dbms_utility.get_time;
dbms_output.put_line(l_end - l_start);
end;
```

```
declare
type nt_test is table of test112.col3%TYPE;
nt_val nt_test := nt_test();
cursor c is select col3 from test112;
c_limit integer := 100;
l_start integer;
l_end integer;
begin
l_start := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
open c;
loop

fetch c 
bulk collect into nt_val limit c_limit;
exit when nt_val.count = 0;

forall i in indices of nt_val
update test111 set col2 = col2/ 5
where col1 = nt_val(i);
commit;

end loop;
l_end := dbms_utility.get_time;
dbms_output.put_line(l_end - l_start);
end;
```

I get 0.797 sec in the merge query and 171.352 with bulk collect

Comment: How many rows are concerned? Why `100` as a limit? committing in a loop is very often a performance killer.

Comment: SQL to PL/SQL engine is a context switch which consumes more time and resources. Simply run the MERGE statement without using any anonymous block. If you need the execution time, then run it in sqlplus and set time on timing on.

Comment: If I gave you a spoon, bucket and a bath full of water and then asked you to empty it as quickly as possible, what would you use? You might say the bucket, but it's actually faster to pull the plug! In database terms, the spoon represents row-by-row processing (e.g. a cursor for loop), the bucket represents bulk collect processing, and pulling the plug is the SQL solution.

Comment: *If normal update (merge) is faster than bulk collect, then why Oracle has introduced it?* Because they are not the same. You might want to populate an array for some other reason. An array might be passed into your procedure as a parameter, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you can do it in SQL, it is almost always more efficient to do it in SQL.  If you have to resort to PL/SQL because you're doing some processing that benefits from procedural code, doing a `bulk collect` and a `forall` will be more efficient than the old style row-by-row processing (though if you're using implicit cursors, recent versions of Oracle will be doing a `bulk collect` automatically behind the scenes so the difference isn't as big as it was).

In your test, I'd expect the commit in the loop to account for most of the difference in runtime.  Obviously, that is functionally different than the SQL solution.

Comment: Overall, agree with Justin. Would like to explain more fully, however, this comment:

"(though if you're using implicit cursors, recent versions of Oracle will be doing a bulk collect automatically behind the scenes so the difference isn't as big as it was)."

(1) If you are executing a cursor FOR loop and inside that you execute row-by-row DML (insert, update, delete), Oracle will automatically optimize the CFL to return 100 rows with each fetch. This is similar to FETCH-BULK COLLECT-LIMIT 100. But it's not actually re-coded as a BULK COLLECT statement. It's in C code by that time. :-)

Comment: (not used to dealing with SO limits on comments) (2) This will not help with the row-by-row DML execution, which is where you will REALLY be feeling the pain. So the advice is good primarily for "read only" cursor FOR loops that don't contain any non-query DML.

Comment: Thank you @Justin Cave ! Thank you for the clarification on this topic. I tested it again and I see the time gain now :)

Comment: Thank you @Steven Feuerstein ! for the clarification

Answer (score 2):

If you can do it in SQL it will be always faster but even then 171.352 is very high value. So I did my test and I added an index on test111(col1) and with same pl/sql block it has completed in 0.20 secs.

Comment: Just a historical note. The assertion implied in the question "If normal update (merge) is faster than bulk collect, then why oracle has introduced it?" Is incorrect as Merge was introduced in version 9i while bulk collect was introduced previously in 8 (or 8i).